# How to make a file completely undetectable

Tags: filesystems

I have the following question: Is it possible to hide a file, such that it cannot be detected be any program? For example if I hide a file like **C:\file.x** I can still find it with the cmd command `dir /a:h C:\`.

Is it possible to make such a file/ directory completely undetectable? Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: no

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sure, just delete it! It will be overwritten eventually of course.

Comment: One possibility>>>>>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography

Comment: Hiding files completely requires a kernel driver which manipulates the file-system calls and removes the files/folders to be hidden. Note that this behavior is usually considered malicious as it is often used by rootkits/malware.

Comment: you want to hide it and be it for only you to find, or you want to actually get rid of it, make it unfind-able even by you?